# Source code transformations to get a set of functional equivalent programs

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

Modern compilers use sourcecode transformations for optimization [1]. It is also shown, that the dynamic randomization of the adress space can be used to combat attacks on programs [2].

In contrary to obfuscators, which try to simply obfuscate the source code, I want to create a set of functional equivalent source code, with permutations for diversity and security with C++.

For example, the following lines

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
int c = 15;
int d = a + b + c;
```

can be transformed into

```
int c = 15;
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
int d = a + b + c;
```

and the two blocks are functional equivalent.

Are there existing tool or methods, which can be used for this purpose?

[1] https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath#Transformations

[2] https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/sec03/tech/full_papers/bhatkar/bhatkar.pdf

Comment: I don't really understand the goal "with permutations for diversity and security with C++" :-(

Comment: To most (optimising) compilers, both code snippets are the same.  They will choose their own order if performance improvement can be achieved..

Comment: @KerrekSB The goal is to create different versions of source code, so that, for example, variables are ordered differently in the address space. That means that attackers can not rely on fixed addresses. Though the main purpose would be to introduce diversity for hardware fault tolerance and software-fault detection.